# Find the mistake: $A=\emptyset\land B=\emptyset\leftrightarrow A\times B=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, quantifiers, fake-proofs

> Find the mistake that for all $A$ and $B$, $$A=\emptyset\land B=\emptyset\leftrightarrow A\times B=\emptyset.$$

The "proof":

$$
\begin{align*}
A=\emptyset\land B=\emptyset&\leftrightarrow\neg(\exists x\,x\in A)\land\neg(\exists y\,y\in B)\tag{1}\\
&\leftrightarrow\forall x\,\neg(x\in A)\land\forall y\,\neg(y\in B)\tag{2}\\
&\leftrightarrow\forall x\,x\notin A\land\forall y\,y\notin B\tag{3}\\
&\leftrightarrow\forall(x,y)\,(x,y)\notin A\times B\tag{4}\\
&\leftrightarrow\neg(\exists(x,y)\,(x,y)\in A\times B)\tag{5}\\
&\leftrightarrow A\times B=\emptyset\tag{6}
\end{align*}
$$

I think the mistake is on $(3)\leftrightarrow(4)$, but I am not able to justify why it is a mistake. Could you help me?

Comment: 3 to 4 is an implication

Comment: @DavidPeterson thank you for the comment!! Yes, I think it too... Can you explain why the implication holds? Or provide a link.

Comment: To show $(4) \not\to (3)$.  You just need a single counterexample.  Try, e.g. $A = \{1\}, B = \emptyset$  what is $A \times B$? [Prove your answer]  Now look at which lines are true for this choice of sets.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks!! $A\times B=\emptyset$, so $(4)$ holds. I am not sure what I have to write in $\forall x\,x\notin A$, because $\forall y\,y\notin B$ is true (because it is true that for any element, those elements are not in $B$ because $B$ is the empty set). But I don't know what to say about the other proposition. Could you help me?

Comment: @DavidPeterson how would you prove it? I couldn't: \begin{align*}\forall x\,x\notin A\land\forall y\,y\notin B&\to\forall x\,\neg(x\in A)\land\forall y\,\neg(y\in B)\tag{a}\\&\to\forall x\forall y\,\neg(x\in A)\land\neg(x\in B)\tag{b}\\&\to\forall x\forall y\,\neg(x\in A\underbrace{\lor}_{\text{It should be $\land$}} x\in B).\tag{c}\end{align*}

Comment: Perhaps you should try the contrapositive with very small sets for intuition.

Comment: If the cartesian product is empty, does that mean both of the sets are?

Comment: @DavidPeterson excellent hint. So to prove $(3)\to(4)$ I will use $\neg(4)\to\neg(3)$: \begin{align*}\exists(x,y)\,(x,y)\in A\times B&\to\exists x\,x\in A\land\exists y\,y\in B\\&\to\exists x\,x\in A\\&\to\exists x\,x\in A\lor\exists y\,y\in B.\end{align*} Now it is correct?

Comment: @DavidPeterson of course it does not mean that, it can be one empty and the other not.